# Number of maximum edges in a simple graph

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, graph-theory, combinations

There are $n$ points in a graph. Each point could connect with at most $k$ other points. No point can be connected with $k+1$ or more points. What is the maximum number of edges in this graph?

---

Not a homework. I guess the answer is $n$ for $k=2$ but not sure how to prove it. Similarly there should be a upper bound of $E\leq \frac{kn}{2}$?

Comment: Have you heard of the [handshake lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a well-know result that $2m = \sum_{v \in V(G)} d(v)$, where $m$ denotes the number of edges of the graph and $d(v)$ denotes the degree of the vertex $v$ (the degree of a vertex $v$ is the number of vertices to which $v$ is connected). This result is called the *Handshake Lemma*.

If the degree of every vertex (or, as you call it, point) is at most $k$, then $2m \leq n k$, so the maximum number of edges you can have is $m=
\frac{nk}{2}$.

Comment: You mean, the maximum number of edges is $\left\lfloor\frac{nk}2\right\rfloor.$ But you have only proved that the maximum is $\le\left\lfloor\frac{nk}2\right\rfloor.$ To prove that the bound is attained, you have to show that some regular (or almost regular) graphs can be constructed.

Comment: If you have a graph with $n$ vertices, then the maximum degree a vertex can have is $n-1$, so in this case $k=n-1$. If every vertex has degree $n-1$, then the graph is $K_n$,which has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{nk}{2}$ edges.

Comment: The problem is to show that, for integers $n$ and $k,$ where $1\le k\le n,$ the maximum possible number of edges for a graph $G$ with maximum degree $\Delta(G)\le k$ is $\left\lfloor\frac{nk}2\right\rfloor.$ You have shown that this is an upper bound, but you have not shown that it is attained. This requires constructing, for given integers $1\le k\le n,$ a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, $\left\lfloor\frac{nk}2\right\rfloor$ edges, and maximum degree $k.$ If $k=n-1$ the complete graph $K_n$ works. This leaves the cases $k=1,2,3,\dots,n-2.$

Comment: Ooh, I see what you mean, yes that is actually an excellent point. I'll have to think it through and come back to the problem.